# iPhone 4s stuck at apple logo in boot

Tags: iphone, ios, startup

My iPhone 4s 64GB was recently updated to iOS7.

The battery was completely empty so I had to charge it.
However, the iPhone does not boot anymore and it's stuck at the Apple Logo.

I went to a service center and they say it's on recovery mode and I have to re-install the software, but data will be lost.

I have a lot of important data, how can I save these?

Comment: Didn't you ever make a backup before?

Comment: If the iPhone won't show up in iTunes on your own machine your data is gone. However did you tried a hard reset by holding power + home?

Answer (score 1):

If it doesn't boot and the device isn't jailbroken, you can't get the data off it.

Hopefully you have an iCloud backup that you can restore to after restoring iOS (using recovery/DFU mode).